# How to avoid ExpandoObject flattening?

Tags: c#, odata, expandoobject

Model looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public ExpandoObject Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

What I get as a result from Web API call:

```
[
    {
        Id: 1,
        Attribute1: "XYZ",
        Attributes: "ABC"
    }
]
```

What I expect to get:

```
[
    {
        Id: 1,
        Attributes:
        {
            Attribute1: "XYZ",
            Attributes: "ABC"
        }
    }
]
```

Controller action returns IQueryable.

```
public IQueryable<Foo> Get()
{
    var result = ...;
    return result.AsQueryable();
}
```

`result` variable is a collection of Foo objects.
Could anybody explain why does it happen?

Comment: You are asking to put Id in the expando as well.  Hard to see why that is necessary.  Do consider the Json.NET library.

Comment: Please post your controller action too. Which JSON serializer do you use?

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the response. Now I see how it looks like, but the real model is much bigger, this one was created for simplicity purposes.

Comment: @Sphinxxx Thanks for your response. The action is not complicated, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found one solution. I'm pretty sure not the best, but working.

I introduced a class containing only one property:

```
public class Bar
{
    public ExapndoObject Content { get; set; }
}
```

and used it in `Foo` class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Bar Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

Anyway, I'm still interested in better solutions.